# Szechuan fish soup ingredient -- what is it?

Tags: fish, soup, chinese-cuisine, food-identification

I got a fish-and-pickled-cabbage soup the other day at a Szechuan restaurant that had these things in it that looked kinda like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=carbon%20nanotube&num=20&newwindow=1&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=h2U&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=wz2WU-b-KrOhsATW74CoCA&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAg). They were translucent off-white, about 2 inches long, and maybe an inch across. They had a light but chewy texture, and at first I thought it was some kind of tripe. What is this stuff?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your description, if it isn't tripe, then it is probably [Bamboo Fungus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_fungus).  This is often used in soup an other dishes and has a neutral flavor.  The texture can be from soft to slightly crunchy depending on the length of cooking.

[image: bamboo fungus soup]

Comment: Phallus indusiatus? That sounds naughty!

Comment: @Jolenealaska Personally, I think *stinkhorn* is even worse.  That's one cruelly named fungus.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, I (had thought at first - see below) that was indeed a form of [tripe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripe), sliced into convenient strips:

[image: honeycomb tripe]

[image: more photogenic tripe]

This is known specifically as "honeycomb" or "pocket" tripe, and is made from the second chamber of a cow's stomach, anatomically called the *reticulum*.  It and other varieties of stomach are fairly common in traditional [Szechuan cuisine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szechuan_cuisine).

EDIT: Well, I thought that I had it for sure, but I think [erichui's answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/44756/25059) is actually correct.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. But they were in cylinders (like the nanotubes picture), not sheets, and there was no "outside" part. It was *just* the honeycomb. Also, the size of each "cell" in the honeycomb was much smaller than that. In hindsight, though, the funky taste does remind me of what little tripe I've had.

Comment: @user25359 Perhaps veal tripe, then; the stuff does seem to come in a tubelike form before being broken down, and it sounds like you're describing a smaller version.  See the second picture I added above.

Comment: I'm still not sure. It wasn't just tube-like, it was complete tubes, like extra-wide rigatoni. Also there was no outside "skin" on it.

Comment: Fun fact of the day: _reticulum_ is Latin for 'net', hence the name of this lovely tripe. The word can also be seen elsewhere in the names of certain animals, like the _reticulated_ python or the _reticulated_ chipmunk, both of which have net-like markings. Thanks for watching.